# Accessing relationship of a relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, relationship

I am adding in an announcements feature to my application.

I have an `announcements` table which stores the announcement and an `announcement_active` table which stores the **undismissed** announcements for each user.

When an announcement is created, a record is generated in the `announcements` table to store this and a record entered in to the `announcement_active` table for every user for that announcement.

My user model holds a relationship for the *active announcements*:

```
public function activeAnnouncements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ActiveAnnouncements');
    }
```

I am then accessing this in my view to check for any **undismissed** announcements like this:

```
@if (Auth::user()->activeAnnouncements()->count() > 0)
    //code
@endif
```

The above works fine, it is when I am trying to do a `for each` loop on the announcements that I am having trouble:

```
@if (Auth::user()->activeAnnouncements()->count() > 0)
    @foreach(Auth::user()->activeAnnouncements()->announcement as $announcement)
      //code to display announcement
   @endforeach
@endif
```

It is when I am chaining `->announcement` that I run in to trouble. I have defined the relationship like so:

```
public function announcement()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Announcements');
    }
```

However I get the error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$announcement

When using Tinker and running `\App\User::find(1)->activeAnnouncements()->first()->announcement` the correct announcement shows.

Where am I going wrong when trying to load these in to my foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never actually retrieving the data in your foreach. Instead, Laravel thinks you're saying "build this query, don't execute it, then look for a property called 'announcement' on it". If you just change it to a `get()` call, it should work:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->activeAnnouncements()->get() as $announcement)
```

Or better yet, use the automatic property version:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->activeAnnouncements as $announcement)
```

By the way, it looks like you might want to check out Blade's `@each` functionality: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#rendering-views-for-collections

Comment: I literally just arrived at the `->get()` solution as you answered. However I definitely like the automatic property version more. Will check out that `@each` functionality shortly, at a glance it looks useful! Thanks Joel!

Answer (score 0):

In your class User, definine a `announcements` relation like this :

```
public function announcements() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Announcement::class,ActiveAnnouncement::class);
}
```

You can then access user's announcement with `announcement` :

```
@if (Auth::user()->announcements()->count() > 0)
    @foreach(Auth::user()->announcements as $announcement)
      //code to display announcement
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Nota :
Maybe you could simply add a column `is_active` in announcement and drop ActiveAnnouncement model. This way, define `announcements` relation in your class `User` :

In your class User, definine a `announcements` relation like this :

```
public function announcements() {
    return $this->hasMany(Announcement::class);
}
```

and access active announcements via :

```
$activeAnnouncements = $user->announcements()->whereIsActive(true)->get()
```

Hope this will help